# Most efficient way to return common elements from two string arrays

Tags: java, arrays, compare

In Java, what's the most efficient way to return the common elements from two String Arrays? I can do it with a pair of for loops, but that doesn't seem to be very efficient. The best I could come up with was converting to a `List` and then applying `retainAll`, based on my review of a [similar SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1235033/java-comparing-two-string-arrays-and-removing-elements-that-exist-in-both-array):

```
List<String> compareList = Arrays.asList(strArr1);
List<String> baseList = Arrays.asList(strArr2);
baseList.retainAll(compareList);
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

#### EDITED:

This is a one-liner:

```
compareList.retainAll(new HashSet<String>(baseList));
```

The `retainAll` impl (in AbstractCollection) iterates over `this`, and uses `contains()` on the argument. Turning the argument into a `HashSet` will result in fast lookups, so the loop within the `retainAll` will execute as quickly as possible.

Also, the name `baseList` hints at it being a constant, so you will get a significant performance improvement if you cache this:

```
static final Set<String> BASE = Collections.unmodifiableSet(new HashSet<String>(Arrays.asList("one", "two", "three", "etc")));

static void retainCommonWithBase(Collection<String> strings) {
    strings.retainAll(BASE);
}
```

If you want to preserve the original List, do this:

```
static List<String> retainCommonWithBase(List<String> strings) {
   List<String> result = new ArrayList<String>(strings);
   result.retainAll(BASE);
   return result;
}
```

Comment: retainAll seems to iterate on the set, and does not lookop on the set (which is kinda weird, it could have been overriden for all hash based collections)

Comment: @SebastienLorber Thanks for pointing that out. I ave incorporated your comment into my edit

Answer (score 3):

I would use HashSets (and [retainAll](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/AbstractCollection.html#retainAll%28java.util.Collection%29)) then, which would make the whole check O(n) (for each element in the first set lookup if it exists (`contains()`), which is O(1) for HashSet). `List`s are faster to create though (`HashSet` might have to deal with collisions...).

Keep in mind that `Set` and `List` have different semantics (lists allow duplicate elements, nulls...).

Comment: But we don't need to do perform lookups, we need to iterate over the elements in turn.

Comment: better than bruteforce but not quite true. Inserting into the hashset is not O(1), thanks to collisions it is not even O(n) most of the time.

Answer (score 3):

Sort both arrays.

Once sorted, you can iterate both sorted arrays exactly once, using two indexes.

This will be O(NlogN).

Comment: @Burleigh How do you arrive at n log n?

Comment: More or less by abusing the notation :). To sort an array is NlogN in the length of the array. Asymptotically, we only need to consider the longer array - let's call that N (and let's assume that comparisons between strings are fixed cost, which is also not true). So the sort stage is O(NLogN). To find the common elements, we can traverse the arrays in order, only so that's O(N), again assuming that the comparisons are fixed cost. I guess it's more accurate to say that the order is O(MNlogN) where M is the length of the longest string in either array.

Answer (score 1):

retain all is not supported by list. use set instead:

```
import java.util.*;
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String[] strings1={"a","b","b","c"},strings2={"b","c","c","d"};
        List<String> list=Arrays.asList(strings1);
        //list.retainAll(Arrays.asList(strings2)); // throws UnsupportedOperationException
        //System.out.println(list);
        Set<String> set=new LinkedHashSet<String>(Arrays.asList(strings1));
        set.retainAll(Arrays.asList(strings2));
        System.out.println(set);
    }
}
```

Comment: It seems to be, at least in JDK7: http://www.docjar.com/html/api/java/util/ArrayList.java.html

Comment: it may be. i am still using java 6

Answer (score 1):

What you want is called intersection.
See that:
[Intersection and union of ArrayLists in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5283047/intersection-union-of-arraylists-in-java)

The use of an Hash based collection provides a really faster contains() method, particularly on strings which have an optimized hashcode.

---

If you can import libraries you can consider using the Sets.intersection of Guava.

---

**Edit:**

Didn't know about the retainAll method.

Note that the AbstractCollection implementation, which seems not overriden for HashSets and LinkedHashSets is:

public boolean retainAll(Collection c) {
       boolean modified = false;
       Iterator it = iterator();
       while (it.hasNext()) {
           if (!c.contains(it.next())) {
               it.remove();
               modified = true;
           }
       }
       return modified;
   }

Which means you call contains() on the collection parameter!
Which means if you pass a List parameter you will have an equals call on many item of the list, for every iteration!

This is why i don't think the above implementations using retainAll are good.

```
public <T> List<T> intersection(List<T> list1, List<T> list2) {
    boolean firstIsBigger = list1.size() > list2.size();
    List<T> big =  firstIsBigger ? list1:list2;
    Set<T> small =  firstIsBigger ? new HashSet<T>(list2) : new HashSet<T>(list1);
    return big.retainsAll(small)
}
```

Choosing to use the Set for the smallest list because it's faster to contruct the set, and a big list iterates pretty well...

Notice that one of the original list param may be modified, it's up to you to make a copy...

Comment: mmm the retainAll method on ArrayList is overriden. I don't have any IDE here but this is what i found in javadoc

Answer (score 0):

I had an interview and this question was the thing they asked me during technical interview. My answer was following lines of code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

        String[] temp1 = {"a", "b", "c"};
        String[] temp2 = {"c", "d", "a", "e", "f"};
        String[] temp3 = {"b", "c", "a", "a", "f"};

        ArrayList<String> list1 = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(temp1));
        System.out.println("list1: " + list1);
        ArrayList<String> list2 = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(temp2));
        System.out.println("list2: " + list2);
        ArrayList<String> list3 = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(temp3));
        System.out.println("list3: " + list3);

        list1.retainAll(list2);
        list1.retainAll(list3);
        for (String str : list1)
            System.out.println("Commons: " + str);
}
```

Output:

```
list1: [a, b, c]
list2: [c, d, a, e, f]
list3: [b, c, a, a, f]
Commons: a
Commons: c
```

Comment: your list1 and list2 won't print out the element but the address.