# How to find the difference between two arraylist without changing the first arraylist value in Java?

Tags: java

I have two arraylists named fw_week and sw_week...
Now have to calculate fw_diff which is difference between fw_week and sw_week 
and sw_diff which is difference between sw_week and fw_week...

I have used like following script,

```
    fw_diff=fw_week;
    sw_diff=sw_week;
    fw_diff.removeAll(sw_week);
    sw_diff.removeAll(fw_week);
```

In this, am getting the fw_diff correctly but the fw_week value is also changed which now equal to fw_diff, so the second value sw_diff is giving the wrong value, but i don't want to change the fw_week and sw_week values... So please can anyone help me to solve this issue....

Comment: What have you though about the new solution, or you want SO write it for you?

Comment: check this questions http://stackoverflow.com/questions/919387/how-can-i-calculate-the-difference-between-two-arraylists   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1235033/java-comparing-two-string-arrays-and-removing-elements-that-exist-in-both-array

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
fw_diff= fw_week.clone().removeAll(sw_week)
sw_diff=sw_week.clone().removeAll(fw_week)
```

More efficient one:

```
fw_diff= fw_week.clone().removeAll(sw_week)
sw_diff=sw_week.clone().removeAll(fw_diff)
```

Here,`fw_diff` contains intersaction of both the list. So now , for `sw_diff` , we need to remove only `fw_diff`  from `sw_week` . No need to remove all of `fw_week` .

Answer (score 0):

You need to clone the arrays:

```
fw_diff=fw_week.clone();
sw_diff=sw_week.clone();
```

before you do any removing.

Comment: Thank you Mr.Jon but after finishing calculation i dont want to change the fw_week and sw_week values because i need them further calculation....

Comment: @RamkumarP The `fw_week` and `sw_week` lists are untouched because you're working with clones of them, and not the lists themselves.

Comment: @RamkumarP You're using Java, right? http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#clone()

Answer (score 0):

We do the same thing in our application like this:-

Our scenario is we have 2 arraylist and I need to find the difference between first and second arraylist.

Following is the code snippet:-

```
this.lstDifference=(ArrayList<String>) ListUtils.subtract(FirstArrayList,SecondArrayList);
```

The type of arraylist can be changed depending upon your two arraylists.